# OpenCV Gaussian blur breaks Tesseract?

Tags: c++, tesseract

The problem: a week or so ago, in hopes of improving Tesseract's accuracy more, I added a Guassian blur / OTSU binarization combo which results in beautiful binary images like the one attached. I do this in openCV, so the image that I pass to Tesseract is already a binary image (like the one attached). When Tesseract does its pre-processing of the image (even the one posted below) the image becomes corrupted and therefore no meaningful output is produced. See the image below the example input, for an idea of what Tesseract is doing to the image.

The source of the problem is the Guassian blur. If I remove it, the `Thresholded image` that tesseract outputs is not garbled, but it is also not as clean and readable as the binary image I attached. Can I disable Tesseract from pre-processing the images I pass it? Why does a Guassian blur completely ruin Tesseract? I feel as if the input image were as clear as the one I attached, accuracy would be improved.

Both images are of the same column. First is input image, second is the result of Tesseract's image pre-processing.

INPUT TO TESSERACT EXAMPLE:

[image]

TESSERACT CORRUPTION (obtained from `GetThresholdedImage()`:

[image: two]

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to save image data from tesseract (tess.GetThresholdedImage()) and store it to disk after tess.SetImage(), so you can be sure you provided correct image for OCR.

Comment: Alright, this helped a lot! So, the thresholded image was a bunch of horizontal lines, so something was going awry. I eventually tracked it down to the fact that I did, in fact, add a Gaussian blur to the image prior to binarization for an improved image. But the result of the blur and binarization is an image like the one attached above ^^. How can a perfectly binarized image break tesseract? I know tesseract tries to binarize the image, also, but my image is more clear, after testing. Any ideas?

Comment: AFAIK tesseract does not binarize 2 color images. So I guess there is problem how to pass opencv data to tesseract. I posted example that works for me.

Answer (score 1):

This code works for me:

```
 /* filename: test_opencv2.cpp
 * compile:
    g++ -std=c++11 test_opencv2.cpp `pkg-config --cflags opencv` \
    `pkg-config --cflags tesseract` -o test_opencv2 \
    `pkg-config --libs opencv` `pkg-config --libs tesseract`
 * 
 */ 
#include <tesseract/baseapi.h>
#include <leptonica/allheaders.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main() {
    tesseract::TessBaseAPI *api = new tesseract::TessBaseAPI();
    if (api->Init("/usr/local/share/tesseract-ocr/", "eng", tesseract::OEM_TESSERACT_CUBE_COMBINED))  {
      fprintf(stderr, "Could not initialize tesseract.\n");
      return 1;
    }

    api->SetPageSegMode(tesseract::PSM_SINGLE_COLUMN);
    IplImage *img = cvLoadImage("7sqw3.png");
    if ( img == 0 ) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Cannot load input file!\n");
      return 1;
    }
    api->SetImage((unsigned char*)img->imageData, img->width,
                   img->height, img->nChannels, img->widthStep);


    char* outText = api->GetUTF8Text();
    printf("OCR output:\n\n");
    printf(outText);

    api->Clear();
    api->End();
    delete [] outText;
    delete api;
    cvReleaseImage(&img);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this works. I was able to make my code work after I removed the Gaussian blur that I mention in my question. What troubles me now is why that happens? And the fact that using `tess.GetThresholdedImage()` and viewing that image show an inferior binarization, done by tesseract. When `SetImage` is called, tesseract does a thresholding operation(among other things, I'm sure) on the image provided

Answer (score 1):

The destination data looks OK, but it is being written to **wider destination container**, without considering restarting the destination cursor at (x=0, y++) where there's a new line in the source data.

Comment: Hmm. Interesting. I wonder what a Gaussian blur has to do with it

Comment: It's possible that the blur process writing to a _larger_ canvas, to include all of the blurred content. If, for example, the output canvas is bigger than the input canvas, by twice the blur radius, then it's worth checking this out.